# Google App Script onFromSubmit Trigger doesn't trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a spreedsheet, with a sheet feed by a Google Form. unfortunetly, I need special features, like conditional formatting, and data added by google form are added in a new line without format.

So, I did an other sheet, with the same columns, and I had to copy paste from the first one to the second one. I'd like this copy to be automated. So I tried to do it using Google App Script. But it seems like I did something wrong with the trigger.

Here is the code :

```js
function creerTrigger()
{
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('deplacerCommande').forSpreadsheet("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").onFormSubmit().create();
}

function deplacerCommande(e)
{
  var id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  var feuille = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName("Commande");
  feuille.appendRow(e.namedValues);
}
```

When I run deplacerCommande() from Google App Script, the messageBox is displayed, but not when a form is submitted, so I don't think the trigger works.

Yes, I created my trigger. I did it by running the function creerTrigger() from Google App Script. I also tried deleting it, then changing the version, then recreating it, because I read it can solve the problem, but it didn't.

[list of trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J6VZ.png)

It's in French, but I'll translate the value for you :
deplacerCommande is the name of the function called by the trigger.
the second value means From the spreedsheet.
the third means sending Form

Comment: I would guess that the error is related to trying to display a message box in this context.  Triggers will run even when no one has the spreadsheet open so there would be no one there to see the msgbox.

Comment: You can also set the notification on the trigger to immediate so that you get an error message sent to you fairly soon after the error occurs.

Comment: You may wish to check to see if the trigger already exists before you create another.

Comment: I confirm the first comment, triggers can not show anything in the UI, browser class is included in this restriction.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. the message box was just for trying to understand why it doesn't work, or if it really triggers. It already didn't worked before I added the messageBox.

I checked, there is no other triggers. But I'll set notification on it, and will send an other form to see if it triggers or not.

Comment: I have just found an error in the log. The trigger triggerred! But it seems like appendRow() can't accept an object. I thought e.namedValues was an array, and would be accepted by appendRow(). I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. The trigger triggered, but the appendRow function raised an Exception because namedValue is an object, not an arrow. using e.values instead of e.namedvalues solved the problem!